# Cannot be on the principal side of a non-ownership relationship

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

I'm looked at examples and solutions with the same error but can't seem to resolve this.

- I have an aggregate root with a one to one relationship with a child entity.
- This child entity has a one to many relationship with its own child
  entity.
- I would like to enforce foreign key constraints
- I am using .net 7 and ef core

My basic entity type configuration is as follows:

```
 public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Person> builder)
    {
        base.Configure(builder);
        builder.HasKey(f => f.PersonId);

builder.OwnsOne(x => x.Wallet, a =>
        {
            a.HasKey(f => f.WalletId);
            a.WithOwner().HasForeignKey(f => f.PersonId);
         
            a.OwnsMany(p => p.Transfers, b =>
            {
                b.HasKey(f => f.TransferId);
                b.WithOwner().HasForeignKey(g => g.WalletId);

                b.HasOne(f => f.DestinationWallet).WithMany(g => g.Transfers).HasForeignKey(p => p.DestinationWalletId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
                b.HasOne(f => f.SourceWallet).WithMany(g => g.Transfers).HasForeignKey(p => p.SourceWalletId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
            });
});
```

I get the following error:

> The relationship from 'Transfer.DestinationWallet' to 'Wallet' is not
> supported because the owned entity type 'Wallet' cannot be on the
> principal side of a non-ownership relationship. Remove the
> relationship or configure the foreign key to be on 'Wallet'.

Any ideas how I can achieve my foreign key constraint with this setup?

Comment: As the exception says: *or configure the foreign key to be on 'Wallet'*.

Comment: Most probably in this model you have to change the "owned" entity types to "normal" entity types.